# Fluent API One-to–Zero-or-One becomes Many-to-One relationship in Database

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to create a One-to–Zero-or-One relationship between two tables in a Code First design with Fluent API. But when it gets created, the relationship in database has become a Many-to-One relationship. I have looked at several tutorials and many Questions on forums but I can't find the problem with my code.

Generated Database Scheme:

[Scheme on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFBjP.jpg)

My DbContext file:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Eigendommen>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Gronden>().HasKey(g => g.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Eigendommen>()
                    .HasRequired(g => g.Grond)
                    .WithOptional(e => e.Eigendommen);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Base class of the table:

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }

    public EntityBase()
    {

    }
}
```

My Main table(One):

```
public class Eigendommen : EntityBase
{
    public string Gemeente { get; set; }

    public string Straat { get; set; }

    public int Grond_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Gronden Grond { get; set; }

    public Eigendommen() : base()
    {
        Gemeente = "Eksaarde";
        Straat = "Ramstraat";
    }
}
```

My second table(Zero-or-One):

```
public enum TypeGround { Bebouwd, Verkaveling };

public class Gronden : EntityBase
{
    public double Opp { get; set; }
    public TypeGround Type { get; set; }

    public virtual Eigendommen Eigendommen { get; set; }

    public Gronden() : base()
    {
        Opp = 11;
        Type = TypeGround.Bebouwd;

    }

}
```

I don't see a difference with the many tutorials I followed, I hope you can see the problem?

If you need more code, just ask!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For a one-to-one/zero relationship the tables should have identical PK columns and the PK columns of one should be the FK to the other.  So set up the `Id` in `Eigendommen` to be the FK instead of `Grond_Id`

Comment: I added the Entitybase class from wich every table inherits. I has an Id field that is used for the PK. So the Id fields are the same I think? I have to use it like that for a school project otherwise I wouldn't use it like that.

Comment: Just as a comment, I’d be curious to know how much time you’re spending working out these sort of issues as opposed to designing and implementing the scheme by hand? :)

Comment: Well, I have to make this for a school project. That's why I have to do it ;)

Comment: @theMayer Yeah, I much perfer DB-first, but I guess I'm just old school ;)

Comment: @juharr You are right in general, just the FK should be the PK of the dependent entity `Gronden`.

Comment: @sam- the lesson here is that ORM tools are to be avoided at all costs! As is Oracle, if you’re ever in a position to make that decision 

Comment: @theMayer Not really an option now :(